# use lwrp with chef-solo

Tags: chef-infra, nrpe, lwrp

I'm using chef-solo with librarian-chef to manage my servers. Here's the structure I have locally:

`Cheffile
Cheffile.lock
cookbooks
data_bags
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
.git
.gitignore
nodes
README.md
roles
tmp`

Each node from the `nodes/` dir has a role defined and I've added most of the generic attributes in the roles.

I've included the [nrpe cookbook](https://github.com/tas50/chef-nrpe) in one of the roles and it's working for the generic part:

```

```
"apache" => {

    "timeout" => 5,
    "keep_alive" => 'On',
    "max_keep_alive_requests" => 100,
    "keep_alive_timeout" => 5,

    "prefork" => {
        "start_servers" => 5,
        "min_spare_servers" => 5,
        "max_spare_servers" => 10,
        "max_clients" => 100,
        "max_requests_per_child" => 1000
    }
},
"nrpe" => {
    "server_port" => 5666,
    "connection_timeout" => 300,
    "dont_blame_nrpe" => 1,
    "command_timeout" => 60,
    "allowed_hosts" => ["10.1.1.10,10.11.1.11"],

 }
```

}
override_attributes(attrs)

```

I'm now trying to use the [LWRP provided by the cookbook](https://github.com/tas50/chef-nrpe/blob/master/examples/base_monitoring.rb) to set up checks in the chef created nrpe.cfg

Any syntax I was able to think about doesn't seem to work though. The `knife solo bootstrap nodename` either exits with syntax errors or completes, but nothing is added on the node. Any insight on how to add this:

`nagios_nrpecheck 'check_load' do
  command "#{node['nagios']['plugin_dir']}/check_load"
  warning_condition '6'
  critical_condition '10'
  action :add
end`

in the `nrpe` block from the role file above will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add an LWRP to a runlist in a role.  You must wrap the LWRP declaration in a recipe and then add the recipe to the role's runlist or the nodes runlist.

**`my_wrapper_cookbook/recipes/nrpecheck.rb`**

```
nagios_nrpecheck 'check_load' do
  command "#{node['nagios']['plugin_dir']}/check_load"
  warning_condition '6'
  critical_condition '10'
  action :add
end
```

**`role`**

```
....
  run_list: {
    "recipe[my_wrapper_cookbook::nrpecheck]"
  }
....
```